# Make container div clear when its content can't fit in one line?

Tags: html, css

I have a liquid layout. When the layout is wide enough some divs (.one and .two) can all line up horizontally on one line.

When the layout is squeezed eventually the right floated divs (.two) end up on multiple lines. Is there a way (without width based media queries) to make the left floated divs clear onto their own line when they cant all fit in a line. I assume I would need to be clear .cont2.

Below is my code an images of what im trying to achieve.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JcDlh

```
<div class="cont">

 <div class="one">
 </div>

 <div class="cont2">
   <div class="two"></div>
   <div class="two"></div>
   <div class="two"></div>
 </div>

</div>

.cont {
  background: blue;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.one {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}
.two {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: white
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
.cont2 {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

See example at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kczux

Comment: you need to press "fork" in order to save your changes to the code ;) Right now we see the original one

Comment: @RiaElliger Thank you! I am a bit wiser now!

Answer (score 0):

to make them all together go to the next line (instead of one by one) you could use a float on the cont2 element. But for making it float to the left instead to the right, I think you need media queries.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jbjmp

Comment: I think that media queries are the way to go here if `.cont2` needs to be flush right when displayed as a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your CSS:   .cont2 { float: right; }

It will make your cont2 div stick to the right with all of his child divs, and when you resize screen it will go to new line. For lower resolutions you will need media queries

Comment: plz check existing answers that tell exactly the same before you add a new one ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries for this, this is my take:
http://jsfiddle.net/S4R6h/

You can read a little here about how to target various devices based on size: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Make the fiddle window very wide and you'll see what you've got when your code sits nicely in a line. Then shrink the window and the media query kicks in and for the purposes of showing you, the body will go black.

HTML:

```
<div class="cont">

 <div class="one">
 </div>

 <div class="cont2">
   <div class="two"></div>
   <div class="two"></div>
   <div class="two"></div>
 </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cont {
  background: blue;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.one {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}
.two {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: white
}

@media only screen 
and (max-width : 1530px) {
/* Styles */
    /* when the query kicks in we decend into night */
    body{
        background: #000;
    }
    .one {
      background: red;
      width: 100%;
    }    
    .two{
        width: 33.333%;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With media queries this would be quite easy, I recommend checking those out. But if you're not willing to use them you could do the following:

Add display:inline-block to .cont2

```
.cont2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And remove the float:left from .one and instead of it add there display: inline-block; too. So .one would look like

```
.one {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

That way the .cont2 div will align to the left when there's not enought space for it to be on the same line with .one .

Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLljt